# Cant get mysql db to update from php website xubuntu 22.04-mysql 8..0.3 php 7.4.30

Tags: server, xubuntu, apache2, mysql, php

I'm not that good with code and basically copy and modified stuff to get it to work for my purposes without fully understanding it. Now I'm having issues trying to create a webpage that will allow me to update one entry in the database.

[image]

A lot of this is taken from the original program (SAM Broadcaster) Here is the code I have come up with but it has no results and I don't really see any errors to help steer me to what is wrong.

clsss.song.php

```
.....snip....... public static function getRequestedSong($requestID) {
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    try {
        $select = $db->select()
                     ->from(array('s' => 'songlist'),
                            array('s.*',
                                  'songID' => 's.ID',
                                  'requestID' => 'r.ID',))
                        ->join(array('r' => 'requestlist'),
                                     's.ID = r.songID',
                                     array('dedicationName' => 'name',
                                           'dedicationMessage' => 'msg'))
                        ->where('r.ID = ?', $requestID);

        $row = $db->fetchRow($select);
        if (!is_null($row)) {
            $song = new self();
            $song->setValues($row);
        }
    } catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $ex) {
        echo "Please verify database settings.<br />";
        exit;
    }
    return $song;
}

public function setRaiseWeight() {
    //Increase Song Weight 
    $query = "UPDATE samdb.songlist SET weight = (weight + 1) WHERE (ID = $currentSong->ID)";
    Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);
          
}

public function setLowerWeight() {
    //Lower Song Weight 
    $query = "UPDATE samdb.songlist SET weight = (weight - 1) WHERE (ID = $currentSong->ID)";
    Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);           
}

public function setValues($songinfo) {
    $properties = get_class_vars(get_class($this));
    $methods = get_class_methods($this);
    unset($methods[array_search('setValues', $methods)]);.........snip......
```

display.playing.php

```
            ....snip..... <br />
                                 <br />
                                 Track requested by <span id="dedication-name">"<?php echo $currentSong->dedicationName; ?>"</span>
                                     <?php if(!empty($currentSong->dedicationMessage)) : ?>
                                        with message <span id="dedication-message">"<?php echo $currentSong->dedicationMessage; ?>"</span>
                                     <?php endif; ?>
                                <!-- END:DEDICATION -->
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Play Weight Status:
                                <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <button class="button" type="button" onclick="<?php echo setRaiseWeight ?>">+</button>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $currentSong->weight; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <button class="button" type="button" onclick="<?php echo setLowerWeight ?>">-</button>
                                <br />   
                                <br />
                                Coming up
                                <br />......snip...
```

I been racking my brain and looking examples but this is all I can come up with. It fails with no errors but I don't even know if the `onclick=` is actually calling the function or if the function is taking the `$currentSong->ID` in the `class.song.php`. I do know that when I added it as a test in `display.playing.php`, it produces/prints the table's id number for the correct entry. I'm stumped but again I don't really know much about coding ... I'm just copying and pasting. I also added a bit of the code before what I added that seems to deal with the db in a different manor but I couldn't understand that version. I know the code I entered is what mysql-workshop says works .. and it does work in there to change the weight... though in mysql the line is more like

`UPDATE samdb.songlist SET weight = (weight + 20) WHERE weight > 50 AND weight < 70;`

`UPDATE` samdb`.`songlist`SET`weight `= '2' WHERE (`ID `= '33');`

there are single quotes and other markings (lol that screwed up putting the code in this post) but in mysql-workshop both codes work with or without the markings. I'm sure I'm just getting the syntax incorrect but I can not figure it out.

Any help for this incompetent brain dead non-coder would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The Execute functions on the Db instance produce a Result object, which you can use to see if the query was successful. So you do `$result =  Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);` and then something like `var_dump($result)` to see what's inside the Result object.

Comment: This did at least give me something to look at .. unfortunately it shows something is not right .. it comes up `NULL` but I tried it with a different part of the code that uses `$db = Database::getInstance();` so I used `var_dump($db)` and it dumped a bunch of stuff .. so my code isn't working .. or not getting any results .. thanks for at least giving me a tool to at least see a bit more of what is going on :)

Comment: You could also turn on general logging in the MySQL server to see the actual SQL statement being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved ... though I don't believe it's the most efficient way to have it work. I ended up going with the following in the `<head>` of the display.playing.php:

```
`<?php
 if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
     button1();
 }
 else if(array_key_exists('button2', $_POST)) {
     button2();
 }
 function button1() {
     require_once('../config/conf.php');
     global $link;
     global $currentSong;
     //$link = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");
     $link = mysqli_connect("acutal-address:port", "actual-users-login","actual-users-password", "actual-DB-name");
     if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
     $sql = "UPDATE songlist SET weight = (weight - 1) WHERE (ID='$currentSong->ID')";
     if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        } else {
     echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
     }
  mysqli_close($link);
 }
    function button2() {
        require_once('../config/conf.php');
        global $link;
        global $currentSong;
        //$link = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");
        $link = mysqli_connect("acutal-address:port", "actual-users-login", "actual-users-password", "actual-DB-name");
        if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
           }
        $sql = "UPDATE songlist SET weight = (weight + 1) WHERE (ID = '$currentSong->ID')";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
     mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>`
```

Then a bit later in the code I added this to the `<body>` :

```
                    <td colspan="4" class="auto-style1">
                                Rating:</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                           <form method="post">
                           <input type="submit" name="button1"
                           class="button" value="-" />
                           </form>
                            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style2">
                                <?php echo $currentSong->weight; ?></td>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                           <form method="post">
                           <input type="submit" name="button2"
                           class="button" value="+" />
                           </form>
                        </tr>
```

along with some css editing and working with the page's table structure the final result looks like this
[image]

I still have an issue I haven't figured out yet but its not really a problem since this isn't "publicly used" (its not advertised and would subject to being stumbled upon only .. and someone can screw up my radio database .. lol and I did that myself by ignoring it for years .. lol basically all my songs were too low of a weight to play now I have to rework all the weights)

I cant seem to get it to connect to the db in the `function button1()/function button2` section when using `$link = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");` when I try to use this it throws an error `ERROR: Could not connect. Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)` I even tried adding `require_once('../config/conf.php');` which has the variables in it but if I use that line anywhere else in the `<head>` or `<body>` such as `<?php echo "$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname" ?>` , it displays the information.... I checked view page source in the browser and the information at least isn't visible to the public so I guess  its functional for my purpose... a little weird .. when you click it the first time it doesn't "seem" to do anything but it does remove or add 1 to the 'weight' then the second click registers the first click ..in other words if the weight is at 50 and I click the minus once it still says its at 50 but its really at 49 (if I check mysql workshop)and if I click it again it will display 49 but the database will be at 48 if I then hit the plus button once at this point it will actually register as if I click the down button it will go to 48 but the DB will be at 49 ... so it always seems to be one off... Those are "quarks" that I can live with but if anyone can give me some insight into why I have to use the physical information in the "function" instead of the variables.